# Insert text between an attribute's value in XSLT1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a xml like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<mObject distName="ABC-1/Schedule-New/ScheduleItem-2002" class="PM">
<p name="Active">1</p>
</managedObject>
<mObject distName="ABC-2/Schedule-New/ScheduleItem-2002" class="PM">
<p name="Active">1</p>
</managedObject>
</data>
```

Now i have to insert a text "XYZ-1" in **mObject** attibute **distName** like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<mObject distName="ABC-1/XYZ-1/Schedule-New/ScheduleItem-2002" class="PM">
<p name="Active">1</p>
</managedObject>
<mObject distName="ABC-2/XYZ-1/Schedule-New/ScheduleItem-2002" class="PM">
<p name="Active">1</p>
</managedObject>
</data>
```

I could achieve that using below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" doctype-system="raml21.dtd" />
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="mObject[@class = 'PM' ]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="distName">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before( @distName,'Schedule-' ), 'XYZ-1/', substring-after( @distName, '/'))"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But few questions here:

1. How does this guarantee that the insertion of XYZ-1 text always happens after 1st occurrence of **"/"** in distName attribute?
2. I want the insertion to happen only after first occurrence of **"/"**.

Any ideas or suggestion????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you want

```
concat(substring-before( @distName,'/' ), '/XYZ-1/', substring-after( @distName, '/'))
```

Comment: Yes.... Error in my xsl...But how do we guarantee that the above happens for 1st occurrence of '/' ?

Comment: @user1529282 because that's the definition of `substring-before` and `substring-after` - they give you the substrings before and after the _first_ occurrence of their second argument within the first argument.